# Gridview Paging with JQuery

Tags: jquery, gridview

Is it possible to handle a gridview's OnPageChanging event with JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

OnPageChanging is a server-side event, and JQuery is a client-side library.

Comment: I understand it is a server control. But you can handle the OnClick of a asp button. I was just wondering if you could do something similar with a GridView paging event. Thanks.

      $('[id$=btnTest]').click(function(evt) {
              evt.preventDefault(); 
            });